# Error: 405 - Method not allowed while trying to update in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Current, I am working on a project using Laravel-5.8. I have a code to update data:

Controller

```
public function store_external_respondent(StoreAppraisalRespondentExternalRequest $request)
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;       
    DB::beginTransaction(); 
  
    try { 

        $respondent = AppraisalRespondent::create([
            'fullname'                  => $request->fullname,
            'respondent_email'          => $request->respondent_email,
            'company_name'              => $request->company_name,
            'is_internal'               => 1,
        ]);  
        
    DB::commit();
    Session::flash('success', 'Appraisal Respondent created successfully');
    return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_respondents.index');        
        
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        DB::rollback();
            Session::flash('error', 'Action failed! Please try again');
            return back();
    }         
}
```

route/web.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'appraisal', 'as' => 'appraisal.', 'namespace' => 'Appraisal', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
  Route::post('appraisal/appraisal_respondents/update_external_respondent/{id?}', 'AppraisalRespondentsController@update_external_respondent')->name('appraisal_respondents.update_external_respondent'); 
});
```

When I did php artisan route:list,  I got:

> |        | POST                                   | appraisal/appraisal/appraisal_respondents/update_external_respondent/{id?}                 | appraisal.appraisal_respondents.update_external_respondent                 | App\Http\Controllers\Appraisal\AppraisalRespondentsController@update_external_respondent               | web,auth

update view blade

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info mr-1 edit-respondent-respondent" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_respondent_external{{ $respondentexternal->id }}">Edit</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="edit_respondent_external{{ $respondentexternal->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <form action="{{route('appraisal.appraisal_respondents.update_external_respondent',['id'=>$respondentexternal->id])}}" method="post" id="edit_respondent-external-form">
             {{ csrf_field() }}
             <input type="hidden" name="appraisal_identity_id" value="{{$identities->id}}">
             <input type="hidden" name="employee_id" value="{{$employees->id}}">
             <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    Update Respondent (External)
                </div>
                 <div class="col-md-12">
                 <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label"> FullName:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                 <input  type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Enter external respondent fullname here" class="form-control" value="{{old('fullname',$respondentexternal->fullname)}}">
                   @error('fullname')
                      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                         <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                     </span>
                     @enderror 
                                                            
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label"> Company:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                  <input  type="text" name="company_name" placeholder="Enter external respondent company here" class="form-control" value="{{old('company_name',$respondentexternal->company_name)}}">
                    @error('company_name')
                     <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                       <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                       @enderror 
                                                            
                     </div>
                     </div>                                                        
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                     <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label"> Respondent Email:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                    <input  type="text" name="respondent_email" placeholder="Enter external respondent email here" class="form-control" value="{{old('respondent_email',$respondentexternal->respondent_email)}}">
                                      @error('respondent_email')
                                       <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                       <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                 </span>
                                 @enderror 
                                                            
                                 </div>
                               </div> 
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                          <button  type="submit" id="edit_respondent_external_btn-submit" class="btn btn-success btn-ok">Save</button>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I submitted, I got this error:

> 405
> Method Not Allowed.
> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. Go Back

In the console I have:

> POST http://localhost:8888/myapp/appraisal/appraisal/appraisal_respondents/update_external_respondent/2 405 (Method Not Allowed)

1. How do I resolve this?
2. Also Why is appraisal repeated twice in

> POST http://localhost:8888/myapp/appraisal/appraisal/appraisal_respondents/update_external_respondent/2 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// STEP 1 
Route::post('appra....

// STEP 2
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
```

So what's wrong?

Comment: I removed <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">  and the problem solved.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please use `{{method_field('check_your_route_type')}}` below `{{ csrf_field() }}`

e.g : `Route::put('url' ...` should use `{{method_field('PUT')}}`